# The conversion of methods of the class in __call()

Tags: php, oop

There is an `Api Client` class that specifies methods that return a specific class. the method name is identical to the name of the class being called.

Question: Is there any way to simplify this? I know about the magic method `__call()`, but I do not understand whether it is possible to implement the same thing through it? Or will it be worse?

```
class ApiClient
{
    private RequestController $controller;

    public function __construct(string $region)
    {
        $this->controller = new RequestController($region);
    }

    public function user(): User
    {
        return new User($this->controller);
    }

    public function rating(): Rating
    {
        return new Rating($this->controller);
    }

    public function weapon(): Weapon
    {
        return new Weapon($this->controller);
    }

    public function achievement(): Achievement
    {
        return new Achievement($this->controller);
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things a magic `_call` solution will cost you are being able to type-hint the returned objects, and losing the compile-time benefits of `use` statements. Those don't work at run-time, so if any of your classes are in different namespaces, you'll need to handle it with string manipulation. if those don't apply, then the answer below will work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal example:

```
class ApiClient
{
    private RequestController $controller;

    public function __construct(string $region)
    {
        $this->controller = new RequestController($region);
    }

    public function __call($methodName, $arguments) 
    {
        // I'm skipping checks that class exists or anything else
        // Also cause class names are case INsensitive you can just:
        return new $methodName($this->controller);

        // Or if case-sensitivity matters
        $methodName = ucfirst($methodName);
        return new $methodName($this->controller);
    }
}
```

Comment: If they want to keep the method names in lower case, you could to add `ucfirst($methodName)` when instantiating the classes.

Comment: I know, but for what purpose?

Comment: Was just typing the same thing up - added the `ucfirst()` as @MagnusEriksson suggests and `!class_exists($class)` to check if the class exists.

Comment: It could be as simple as method names usually starts with a lower case while class names tend to start with an upper case. It's the most common convention at the moment. And that their original class has it that way.

Comment: `new user()` and `new User()` will instantiate the same object, I suppose making something uppercased is useless.

Comment: If you're using an autoloader (like PSR-4 via Composer) on a nix system, then casing matters very much.